# AppCenter iOS Device Testing - the test runner failed to start error

Tags: xcode, visual-studio-app-center, xcuitest, visual-studio-app-center-test

When trying to test:

- Cordova 9 + Angular 8 Hybrid iOS 9 app
- Built in XCode with an XCUITest target added
- Deployed to AppCenter device cloud testing

I have no problems doing UI Tests on devices above iOS 12.3

Below iOS 12.3 I get the following error in AppCenter when doing a device UITest:

```
The test runner failed to start.The XCUITest-RUnner failed to start.
You can normally find clues about the cause of this in the device log.
```

Unfortunately the device log is empty.

I contacted AppCenter support and after a couple of days and getting input from an engineer this was the response:

```
The problem is that your XCUITest Runner is not correctly linked with Swift.
Before iOS 12.3, the Swift dylibs need to be shipped with iOS applications (the -Runner is an iOS application).  Starting in iOS 12.3, the Swift dylibs are part of the OS and do not need to be bundled in the .app.
You need to adjust your Xcode build settings to generate a XCUITest Runner that is compatible with iOS 12 - 13.x.
I don't know how to do this so I cannot offer specific advice.
I hope you can find a StackOverflow post or some Apple documentation.
```

I'm a hybrid developer and I know nothing about swift or native iOS development.  I've tried to research on how to `correctly link the test xcuitest runner with swift` but I'm lost and not getting anywhere.  Can someone provide some help for a newbie?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working.  I made sure all targets were pointing to the same target SDK, in my case iOS 9.  Also, I verified the output folder for my .app which wasn't what I originally thought.  I changed the path in my `appcenter test run` command to point to the proper path.  I found the proper path by opening Xcode, expanding my project, expand the product folder, then right click the *.app file and choose `open in finder`.